# Cannot set '1,2,3' keys for selection type in "Keep UV and Edit Mode Mesh Selection in Sync" mode

Tags: shortcut, uv-image-editor

I have set '1,2,3' hotkeys for vertex edge and face selection type respectively both in 3d View and in UV view. However, when "Keep UV and Edit Mode Mesh Selection in Sync" is de-activated, those buttons don't work, even though I did set them in that mode as well. I tried removing the hotkeys from the non-"Keep UV and Edit Mode Mesh Selection in Sync" mode and then the hotkeys start working in the needed mode. Is there any way to have them in both modes?

[image]

Comment: You have most probably a hotkey conflict here. Go to the input manager in the User Preferences and search for the Numad 1 keybinding. I see the hotkeys Numpad 1 and 2  used by View Zoom Ratio here in the Image Editor.

Comment: Nope, those were deleted beforehand. The truth is, the conflict is between UV Select Mode in the first mode and UV Select mode in the second mode.   Disabling them in one mode allows the others to work. Like I said, I can have either one or the other, but not both. I just wondered if someone managed to get both working.

Comment: Ah. This wasn't clear from your first post. In this case this sounds like something that the devs should have a look at. I would say file a bug report :)